# How to draw in a class from another class

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have this code:

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
private Paint paint;

public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initPaint();
}

public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initPaint();
}

public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initPaint();
}

private void initPaint() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);
}
}
```

How do I run this in another class?

I have `MainActivity` which `setContentView` a layout called `activity_main`. I want to draw a line on `MainActivity` using the code above. How can I do this?

Btw, `activity_main` contains DrawerLayout that contains RelativeLayout containing image and several buttons.

I always see answers that lead to changing the layout for example, `setContentView(draw)` where draw is a newly created class where `dispatchDraw()` is called. I want `activity_main` to be my layout and just draw over it. How can do that?